# How to change format of db date in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Current date formate is like `2015-06-01 18:05:15` how to fetch date from db in require format, I want it in `01-06-2015` format?

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 
                p.recipe_nm, 
                c.category, 
                s.sub_cat_name, 
                r.name                          AS user_name, 
                r.image_path                    AS user_img, 
                FORMAT(p.created, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS PerDate, 
                p.quick_des 
FROM   product p 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_cat_meta pc 
                    ON p.id = pc.cprod_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN prod_sub_meta sm 
                    ON p.id = sm.sprod_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN category c 
                    ON c.id = pc.cat_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sub_category s 
                    ON s.id = sm.sub_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN df_register_users r 
                    ON r.id = p.user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
DATE_FORMAT(p.created, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NAME_COLUMN, "%d-%l-%Y %H:%m:%s") AS 'Date'
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `DATE_FORMAT` function of mysql. See references [in the mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp). The function takes as input your date and the format you want and outputs the date in the given format. See here :

```
 DATE_FORMAT(your_date,'%m-%d-%Y');
```

In your case you are probably looking for (the current date in the format you want):

```
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
```